# mongoose.connection undefined but, mongoose.connections[0] defined

Tags: mongoose

I am using Mongoose to try to close the database connection, here is my code.

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose"
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB")

console.log(mongoose.connection) // 1st console log
console.log(mongoose.connections[0]) // 2nd console log
mongoose.connections[0].close()
```

Why does the 1st console log return undefiend while the 2nd console log return defined? According to the mongoose docs, these are equivivilent.

Tried to close the connection u